# jQuery :selected in IE7

Tags: jquery, select, internet-explorer-7

:selected doesn't seem to work in IE7.

```
var selected_value0 = $("#select").find(':selected').attr('value');
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/clare73/8TLqs/

Comment: The problem is that selected option does not have a value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.attr('value')`, instead use `.val()`

```
var selected_value0 = $("#select").find(':selected').val();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8TLqs/4/)**

Comment: I am not sure, but I am not convinced using `.val()` as `.val` is supposed to return option value property. May be it is just me...

Comment: I think the point is more that `.attr('value')` is what not to use.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/8TLqs/5/ to see what I mean.. that is if he really wanted to select the `text()`

Comment: Yeah I see your point, but the OP isn't use the value attribute, and even if he was, that's probably what he wants.

Comment: To get the options value, I would use `$("#select").val()`. ITo get the selected options text then I would use `$("#select").find(':selected').text()`. Well that is what I was trying to suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Your options list doesn't have a value attribute.. and I assume that you are trying to get the text of the options, not value. If so use `.text()` like below,

```
var selected_value0 = $("#select").find(':selected').text();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8TLqs/1/

Incase if you are trying to get the value of the selected option, then you can simply use `.val()` like below,

```
var selected_value0 = $("#select").val()
```

For which HTML should be,

```
<select id="select">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">choice 1</option> 
   <option value="1">choice 2</ option> 
</select>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8TLqs/6/